# Why do I get "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" when trying to build a template string and then interpolate using %?

Tags: python

I have this working code:

```
print("File: %30s "%("name"))
```

I want to replace the `30` width specifier with a variable.

I tried this approach, but I got an error:

```
>>> leng = 30
>>> print("File: %" + str(leng) + "s " % ("name"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `%` has higher precedence than `+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of order of operations, your code evaluates as:

```
"File: %" + str(leng) + ("s "%("name"))
```

To fix this, just parenthesize the string like:

```
("File" + ...)%("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

The latter one applies `%` only to `"s "`. Use grouping parentheses:

```
print(("File: %" + str(leng) + "s ") % "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really related to OP' request, but using `python3.6` [`f-string`s](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), you can avoid using two levels of string in-place replacement; here is an example:

```
>>> filename = "some name"    
>>> print(f"File: {filename:-^{len(filename)+6}} ")
---some name---
```

For older versions of `python`, the other answers apply.

Answer (score -1):

Instead you could do

```
print("File: {:.30}".format(name))
```

where name is a predefined filename